# In jOOQ, Why I had an error of 'Cannot find setter, adder nor field in org.jooq.util.jaxb.Generator for 'masterDataTables''?

Tags: java, sql, jooq

EDITED
Sorry, my friend told me that I just have to use a newer version of the plugin. Let me told you how it goes!

I am using jOOQ, and today I change a table that previously having single field as a primary key, into multiple key as primary key.
Because of this, all other tables that refer to this table, must be changed too. I changed it by also adding the missing field in that tables.
As I use Maven for Java development, I run into trouble when running 'mvn properties:read-project-properties jooq-codegen:generate'

I got this error of :

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.jooq:jooq-codegen-maven:2.0.5:generate (default-cli) on project collect-core: Unable
to parse configuration of mojo org.jooq:jooq-codegen-maven:2.0.5:generate for parameter generator: Cannot find setter, adder nor field in org.jooq.util.jaxb.Generator for 'masterDataTables' -> [Help 1]
```

What cause this error, on how to fix it?

Thanks
Eko

Comment: I just use version 2.0.1 of jOOQ, and it works just fine.

Comment: Well, I ask this question 10 months ago, and just today I helped myself with my own question. :)